# Subclipse 1.10.13 - Shortcut for Committing all Files of Project instead of only the opened file

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subclipse

I am using Subclipse 1.10.13 and have a shortcut for committing changes of the current file.

The only thing I'm missing is a shortcut for commiting the changes of all files of the current project, not only the selected file.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Thanks in advance!
Ben
PS: I have googled around a bit before this posting and found stuff like http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=394 - but this doesn't help me unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

The commit action is based on the context of the current selection, so I do not think so.  You might try from the Synchronize view as I believe it has a toolbar action to commit everything regardless of what is selected.

Comment: I unfortunately can't find an entry for the toolbar action to commit everything regardless of the selection. But thanks anyway!

Comment: You have to be in Outgoing or Mixed mode but there is a toolbar button on the Synchronize view that says Commit All Outgoing Changes.  This brings up commit dialog with all of the items in it